# The first step in the proof of the Pólya-Vinogradov Inequality.

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, number-theory, inequality

The well-known Pólya-Vinogradov Inequality states:

$$\forall m, n \in \mathbb{N}: \displaystyle \left|{\sum_{k \mathop = m}^{m+n} \left({\frac k p}\right)}\right| < \sqrt p \ \ln p,$$

where $\left({\frac k p}\right)$ is the Legendre symbol.

I would like to write out a nice, detailed proof for personal reference, and I can follow most of the proofs I find well-enough, except for the first step. Many start with the same thing, or close to it:

"Start with the following manipulations: $$\displaystyle \sum_{k \mathop = m}^{m+n} \left({\frac k p}\right)=\displaystyle \frac 1 p \sum_{k \mathop = 0}^{p-1} \sum_{x \mathop = m}^{m+n} \sum_{a \mathop = 0}^{p-1} \left({\frac k p}\right) e^{2 \pi i a \left({x - k}\right) / p}=\displaystyle \frac 1 p \sum_{a \mathop = 1}^{p-1} \sum_{x \mathop = m}^{m+n} e^{2 \pi i a x / p} \sum_{k \mathop = 0}^{p-1} \left({\frac k p }\right) e^{-2 \pi i a t / p}.$$

I have absolutely no idea where this first step comes from. I am especially confused as to why the index of summation changes from how it is originally presented. I am somewhat new to quadratic Gauss sums, which I understand are the whole basis for this.

Thanks very much for any and all input.

Comment: While a reader familiar with quadratic Gauss sums is probably aware, you may want to mention that $\left({\frac k p}\right)$ is intended as the Legendre symbol. Also, the following link seems like it might be useful: http://jonismathnotes.blogspot.com/2014/10/character-sums-and-polya-vinogradov.html. (Albeit phrased in terms of Dirichlet characters rather than the Legendre symbol.)

Comment: @Semiclassical Good idea. I have made that change.

Comment: I now have a very nice resolution thanks to Erick Wong below. Thanks again to him. Being relatively new to the community, though, I was wondering why my question did not receive any upvotes? Is this standard procedure since it isn't groundbreaking or profound, or was there some sort of issue with it that I should be aware of? Thanks!

Comment: ...and now it has one. Sheesh. Thanks, whoever!

Comment: @TheCount I'm just speculating, but I'd guess that high-upvote questions tend to be either accessible to a very wide audience (thus catching a lot of fish) or highly original with substantial research effort (thus hooking the regulars).  Maybe in this particular case the title of the question scared off the wide audience, but the actual question itself was fairly routine and didn't attract much attention from the regulars (or they were looking to see if it's a duplicate).  FWIW, I think you're doing a fine job so far.

Comment: @ErickWong Well, now it has 2. I'd imagine one came from you, so thanks. I expected it would get one or two. I certainly wouldn't expect any of my questions at this stage in my mathematical life to fall into the latter category and I hope I can understand most of those that would fall into the former well enough on my own. In any case, thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key idea here is *orthogonality*: the complex number $\omega_r = e^{2\pi ir/p}$ has the property that $\omega_r^p = 1$.  This makes it easy to evaluate $\sum_{a=0}^{p-1} \omega_r^a$, since

$$(1 - \omega_r)(1 + \omega_r + \omega_r^2 + \cdots + \omega_r^{p-1}) = 1 - \omega_r^p = 0.$$

As long as $\omega_r \ne 1$, we can cancel out the first factor to obtain $\sum_{a=0}^{p-1} \omega_r^a = 0$.  On the other hand, if $\omega_r = 1$ it is trivial to evaluate the sum directly as $\sum_{a=0}^{p-1} 1 = p$, which gives the orthogonality relation:

$$ \sum_{a=0}^{p-1} e^{2\pi i ar/p} = \sum_{a=0}^{p-1} \omega_r^a = \begin{cases} p,&\text{if }r\equiv 0 \pmod p; \\ 0, &\text{otherwise}.\end{cases}.$$

Now it's easy to see how the sum unravels.  First, the ranges of summation are independent so we may freely switch the order of the sums:
$$ \frac 1 p \sum_{k \mathop = 0}^{p-1} \sum_{x \mathop = m}^{m+n} \sum_{a \mathop = 0}^{p-1} \left({\frac k p}\right) e^{2 \pi i a \left({x - k}\right) / p} = \frac 1 p \sum_{x \mathop = m}^{m+n} \sum_{k \mathop = 0}^{p-1}  \sum_{a \mathop = 0}^{p-1} \left({\frac k p}\right) e^{2 \pi i a \left({x - k}\right) / p}.$$

The innermost sum is exactly $0$ unless $k \equiv x \pmod p$, and since $k$ goes through a complete system of residues mod $p$ this occurs exactly once for each value of $x$, so we can restrict the sum to just the place where $k=x$.

$$\frac 1 p \sum_{x \mathop = m}^{m+n} \sum_{k \mathop = 0}^{p-1}  \sum_{a \mathop = 0}^{p-1} \left({\frac k p}\right) e^{2 \pi i a \left({x - k}\right) / p} = \frac 1 p \sum_{x \mathop = m}^{m+n} \sum_{k=x}^{x}  \left({\frac k p}\right) p = \sum_{x \mathop = m}^{m+n} \left({\frac x p}\right).$$

Since you're writing a detailed proof, note that even though $m,n$ might well be outside the range $[0,p)$, we can still justify restricting $k=x$ because both the Legendre symbol $(k/p)$ and the exponential term $e^{2\pi ia(x-k)/p}$ are periodic mod $p$.

Comment: Did you forget to switch some summation indices around in the final steps? In any case, thanks very much! I'm beginning to work through this now.

Comment: No, no you did not. I am silly. Thanks again very very much.

Comment: Actually, I have noticed that the manipulation I posted above has $a=1$ as the starting lower index on the inner sum, yet you start with $a=0$. Is this a typographical error or is there more to this? If $a=1$ is indeed correct, I do not see where it comes from (more specifically why it changes from $a=0$ in the process$.

Comment: @TheCount I guess the difference of excluding $a=0$ amounts to $\sum_{x=m}^{n+m} \sum_{k=0}^{p-1} \left(\frac{k}{p}\right)$, so this is using the additional property that $ \sum_{k=0}^{p-1} \left(\frac{k}{p}\right) = 0$, which holds for any *odd* prime (it's easy to prove using the multiplicativity of Legendre symbol and the existence of at least one non-residue).

Comment: Bingo! Many thanks again!